# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).timeDropper is not a function

Tags: jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.timedropper.js'></script>
</head>

<body><input type="text" name="time" id="time" />
  <script>
    $('#time').timedropper();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried to insert auto time on text field but getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).timeDropper is not a function

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+is+not+a+function+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Did you load the [library](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/timedropper) ? 
Do you have more than one jQuery library loaded?

Comment: hi, is it possible the timedropper script wasn't loaded - perhaps try searching for it in chrome dev tools

Comment: I have loaded the scripts

Comment: <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/timedropper.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/timedropper.min.css'
    type='text/css' media='all'/>

Comment: You don't appear to be loading jQuery but then the error message would be different 

Comment: i have included <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/28march2022/flownia/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Look in the network tab. Perhaps you have a 404

Comment: And is jQuery being loaded _before_ timedropper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="timedropper.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> // Path as per your style sheet location
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="time" id="time" readonly="" />

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="timedropper.js"></script> // Path as per your script location
<script>
    $("#time").timedropper();
</script>

</html>
```